# How can I wait for async ngOninit to complete before testing

Tags: angular, promise

I have an `ngOnInit` method that does async work.

How can I execute my `expect` statements once the async work is complete ?

```
it('test things once all the promises declared in ngOninit are resolved', () => {
  comp.ngOnInit();

  // I want to test that comp.property is like expected

});
```

My component methods look like this:

```
OnInit() {
  this.asyncMethod();
};

asyncMethod() {
  this.methodThatReturnsPromise().then(() => {
    this.property = this.otherPropertyNowResolved;
  })
};
```

Comment: How does anything else in your program know when that's complete? What happens inside the callback that you could check for?

Comment: in the call back there is some initialization logic

Comment: Could you expand on that? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I completed my example

Answer (score 9):

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);


it('test things once all the promises declared in ngOninit are resolved', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(
                    () => {
                         // This should run once ngOnInit is completed

                    }
                );
}));
```

Comment: That callback doesn't run after all promises in ngOnint are resolved

Comment: From the information that you have provided, this is what I achieved. Please show more code regarding configuration or try debugging properly. And no need to call `comp.ngOnInit();` explicitly